# Autofill forms on Android from password manager

Tags: android

I want to build an password manager for Android. The Problem is I don't know how to get it to fill login forms of third party applications. I know this is working, because [LastPass](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lastpass.lpandroid) does exactly what I want.

I don't want a complete solution ;) I just need a point to start. Secondly I don't want to replace the system keyboard like [Keepass2Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=keepass2android.keepass2android&hl=de) does. I googled nearly two days about this but I can't get the right keywords to find a starting point.

So the questions are:

- How do I detect login forms on the active activity?
- How do I paste the credentials to this inputs?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the id from a TextView then you need to use [getIdentifier()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) function. You can find a potential usage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203454/how-to-use-getresource-getidentifier-to-get-layout).
When you will get the id from your TextView you can paste a text in your form with something like this

```
instantFromTextView.setText("your creds");
```

I hope to help!