# How do I set text of TextView to a string resource? (Java for android)

Tags: java, android, textview

I would like to change the text of a `TextView` component to another text, that I have already created in `strings.xml`. When the app starts, the text shown is stored in `strings.xml`, under the name "help0". I would like to set this to the string under the name "help00" programmatically, by placing another "0" at the and of the name. So far I have written this code :

```
String help = "0";
help = help + "0";
final TextView help = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.help);
help.setText("@string/help" + help);
```

However, when I run the app the text changes to "@string/help00", instead of the text I have stored under help00 in `strings.xml`.

How could I fix this problem?

Comment: is help00 declared inside your strings.xml file?

Comment: Do you want the "0" at the end of the text or you want to get a string resource id of "help0"?

Comment: @codeMagic, orb it is so confusing, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it's declared. When the app starts, the value of help0 from strings.xml is displayed, and I want to change it to the value of help00 (from strings.xml)

Answer (score 11):

Because You have concatted String resource id with normal String `help` So its worked as a `String`. You have to get first resource string from android resource and then need to concat with local String variable, like,

`help.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.help)+help);`

As I doubt, if you are looking for dynamically String id, You want String resource id with already exist id and '0' append to it then get int resource id from String using..

```
int resourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("@string/help" + help, "string", this.getPackageName());
```

and then

`help.setText(resourceId);`

Comment: I wouldn't like to add a '0' to the displayed text, but to the string's ID, like I change it in the xml from android:text="@string/help0" to android:text"@string/help00". Is there a way I could do this?

UPDATE: I saw your update, thank you :)

Comment: i'd check for values <= 0 before calling setText. On the other hand a more clear syntax is `getIdentifier("help"+help, "string" this.getPackageName());`

Comment: Something similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203454/how-to-use-getresource-getidentifier-to-get-layout

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
String help = "0";
final TextView tvHelp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.help);
String yourString = getResources().getString(R.string.help);
tvHelp.setText(yourString +help)
```

Comment: My problem is, that I am changing the 'stringId', so after I change it what way could I change it to something else? (Exactly adding a '0' at the and of the stringId, so that it would become stringId0)

Comment: This still only adds a '0' to the displayed text as I encountered :(

Answer (score 3):

I believe that strings.xml resource file content cannot be edited during runtime.
now i am assuming u have the following on your strings.xml file

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Application Name</string>
    <string name="help0">Text1</string>
    <string name="hellp00">Text2</string>
</resources>
```

if u want to change the text on your TextView (id=@+id/textview) from the value stored as "help0",to value stored in "help00" use the following code:

```
String text= getString(R.string.help00);
TextView myTextView = findViewById(R.id.textview);
myTextView.setText(text);
```