# How do I access a landscape resource while in portrait mode?

Tags: android, android-resources

The title sums it up: I want to read a landscape XML resource (specifically an integer) while in portrait mode. To be clear, I need to do it in Java code, not XML.

How do I do it?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203454/how-to-use-getresource-getidentifier-to-get-layout and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648942/dynamic-resource-loading-android